# How to dynamically load JavaScript file in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to load a JavaScript file in React on a button click but it is not loading.
The file "filetoload.js" just console.logs('loaded') statement

The file structure is as follows:

```
src
   index.js
   app.js
   filetoload.js
public
   index.html
```

Earlier I used this function to load

[image]

where it was giving error

*Unexpected token '<'
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'*

So, I added type in the function

[image]

still this function does not seem to add the script. I was following this blog https://betterprogramming.pub/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668

I have routing enabled in the application if that affects idk. any help will be appreciated

Comment: Check this [article](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-dynamically-load-a-js-file-in-javascript)

Comment: i have the same code written above, it is not working

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
function loadJS(FILE_URL, async = true) {
  let scriptEle = document.createElement("script");

  scriptEle.setAttribute("src", FILE_URL);
  scriptEle.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  scriptEle.setAttribute("async", async);

  document.body.appendChild(scriptEle);

  // success event 
  scriptEle.addEventListener("load", () => {
    console.log("File loaded")
  });
   // error event
  scriptEle.addEventListener("error", (ev) => {
    console.log("Error on loading file", ev);
  });
}
loadJS("file1_path", true);
```